# Dynamic body content in angular2

Tags: angular

[image]I am loading the header and footer by using the header and footer  component.

In router-outlet i am loading the body content(template).The input field in the body content  contains the absolute position . Due to absolute position  in input field ,it is moving the below the footer .can we have any solution in angular2 to make the body content dynamic ?

Template code :

```
  <div class="screen">
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <button type="submit" class="generated-button" (click)="create()" style="position: absolute;width:  67px;height: 35px;left: 512px;top:400px;">Button</button>
 </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Create one parent element of it and add `position: relative`. Hope this will work.

Comment: how and where did i want create the parent element

Comment: This is code :   <header></header>
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                        <footer></footer>

Comment: You are adding input field in one template correct? which is rendering based on `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ... in that template only...  can you add complete code here that will be helpful.

Comment: @AvneshShakya -  I have added the template code .Please check .

Comment: @AvneshShakya - any info